# Getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while injecting bean dependency through constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to inject a configuration bean into my Service. For this i created a separate class EncryptionProps

```
public class EncryptionProps {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Value("${kafka.properties.security.keyreuseinterval}")
    private long keyReuseInterval;
}
```

Then, i am creating another config class to register this as a bean

```
@Configuration
public class EncryptionConfig {
@Bean
public EncryptionProps encryptionProps() {
    return new EncryptionProps();
}}
```

And this is how, i am calling this in my service class:

```
@Service
public class EncryptionService {   
private final long keyReuseInterval;

//some more declarations    

@Autowired
public EncryptionService(SchemaProcessor schemaProcessor, CryptoLib crypto, EncryptionProps encryptionProps) {
    this.schemaProcessor = Preconditions.checkNotNull(schemaProcessor, "schemaProcessor cannot be null.");
    this.crypto = Preconditions.checkNotNull(crypto, "CryptoLib must be provided");
    this.keyReuseInterval = encryptionProps.getKeyReuseInterval();
}
```

However, when i run this, i am getting the following error -  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.sinkad.kafka.util.EncryptionProps' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I am stuck on this since last day. I have tried tons of stackoverflow questions on this, but none helped so far. Can anybody please help me in why Spring is not finding this bean. I even tried adding @ComponentScan over the EncryptionConfig class. But that also didn't worked. Or if you can just point me to some resource related to it.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here is my main class:

```
package com.example.sinkad;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}}
```

Comment: at-first, are you sure that method `encryptionProps` really called? (print something in it or debug this). at-second, related to first, `@ComponentScan` will not work if your context didn't load this configuration. at-third, did you try to replace constructor injection with field injection?

Comment: Can you try by making `EncryptionProps` a `@Component`

Comment: @ZhenyaM i was earlier using field injection and it was working. But, i was told to move it to constructor based injection as it is a better practice. I will try to debug as you suggested.

Comment: @vizsatiz i did tried making EncryptionProps a Component. But that also didn't worked

Comment: @Ambidextrous , I think your problem is that your context can't look up you `EncryptionProps` and `EncryptionConfig`. Try to add `@ComponentScan` over your main class (`@SpringBootApplication`) and add path to your configuration

Comment: @ZhenyaM that sounds correct to me, as i cannot find a text i printed in the console logs. But, doesn't <@SpringBootApplication> already has <@ComponentScan). this class is in a subpackage of the main class.

Comment: @Ambidextrous yes, but your `@Configuration` class needs to be in a deeper or the same package to be picked up. Keep an eye on that

Comment: @Ambidextrous , we can't to see your package structure, configurations and lot of other things, so it really hard to say what wrong. You could try to use [@Import](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) - it could help, but not cool solution=))

Comment: @LppEdd yes, the class in a sub package of the main class. For example-  main class-> com.example.sinkad .. encryptionclass -> com.example.sinkad.kafka.config

Comment: @Ambidextrous can you post your main class?

Comment: @LppEdd  i have added the main class now

Comment: @Ambidextrous thank you. If you add an empty constructor to `EncryptionConfig`, does it get called? And try removing the `@Value` annotation from `EncryptionProps`

Comment: @LppEdd thanks for the reply. i tried debugging the empty constructor and the encryptionprops method in the encryptionConfig but it doesn't get called. Tried removing annotation..still getting same issue.

Comment: @Ambidextrous it really seems the component scanning isn't working at all for that bean. Did it work before? Which changes have you made in the last hours?

Comment: @LppEdd I even tried explicitly providing component scan on the main application class, even though this package is a nested one. I just added a new class, moved the property there from the field leve and it is failing. When i move back to field level injection it works :(

Comment: @Ambidextrous oh then with field injection it works? I didn't understand that. That's a good clue

Comment: @Ambidextrous would you be able to load all the classes in a GitHub Gist? I think this is a Bean creation ordering problem

Comment: is your package where `EncryptionProps` is present a child package where your main class `Application` is present? and is `kafka.properties.security.keyreuseinterval` present in application.properties?

Comment: @LppEdd sorry i cannot load code on GitHub. Company Policy

Comment: @AmitKBist yes, the class EncryptionProps is present in child package and the property is present in application.properties. It works fine when i move to field level injection instead of constructor

Comment: @Ambidextrous which version of Spring are you on? And do you see errors/warnings in the console log other than that one? Could you maybe post the entire stacktrace

Comment: @LppEdd '@AmitKBist' Thanks guys for suggestions. I have posted what worked for me below. Not sure how it works though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this issue with a team member's help. I am still not sure what was the issue, But here's what we did:

1) Moved the keyReuseInterval value to another config class, which will create the object for EncryptionProps object

```
public class EncryptionProps {
@Getter
@Setter
private long keyReuseInterval;  
}
```

Here 's the config class

```
@Configuration
public class CryptoConfig {

@Value("${kafka.properties.security.keyreuseinterval}")
private long keyReuseInterval;

@Bean
public EncryptionProps encryptionProps() {
    EncryptionProps encryptionProps = new EncryptionProps();
    encryptionProps.setKeyReuseInterval(keyReuseInterval);
    return encryptionProps;
}
```

}

2) And we are calling encryptionProps in the service class similar to before:

```
 @Autowired
public EncryptionService(SchemaProcessor schemaProcessor, CryptoLib crypto, EncryptionProps encryptionProps) {
    this.schemaProcessor = Preconditions.checkNotNull(schemaProcessor, "schemaProcessor cannot be null.");
    this.crypto = Preconditions.checkNotNull(crypto, "CryptoLib must be provided");
     this.keyReuseInterval = encryptionProps.getKeyReuseInterval();
}
```

I am not sure how this fixed the issue. But thought will share it with you guys. Thanks again guys for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
@Component
class EncryptionProps {

    final String keyreuseinterval;

    // Use @Autowired to get @Value to work.
    @Autowired
    EncryptionProps(
        @Value("${kafka.properties.security.keyreuseinterval}") final String keyreuseinterval) {
        this.keyreuseinterval = keyreuseinterval;
    }

}
```